# How do solar panels work in space?

Tags: temperature, space

As you know, the temperature of objects in space is about -260 ° C in the shade and about + 200-300 ° C in the sun.
But here there is a small nuance.
The fact is that the efficiency of solar panels is extremely dependent on temperature, and quickly decreases as it rises above room temperature.
Above +25°C, Si single crystals begin to lose efficiency by about 0.5% with every degree. Heating the surface layer to 60-70°C, which is often the case in summer in hot regions, leads to a loss of 20% of the rated performance, which is a serious problem for users.
For other types of batteries, the coefficient is somewhat lower, up to 0.3%, but the initial value of the efficiency is also lower.
when the silicon battery is heated above 120°C, the battery stops working altogether, and its rapid and irreversible degradation begins.
in addition, solar panels are very sensitive to heating/cooling cycles.
thermal cycling also rapidly degrades the battery.

It turns out that space for solar panels is absolutely not a suitable environment!
Nevertheless, they work there.
How do they do it?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page on spacecraft thermal control? If so, then what is unclear to you in that page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_thermal_control

Comment: According to"[Environmental Conditions for Space Flight Hardware - A Survey](https://nepp.nasa.gov/docuploads/C5E0869C-0469-4D11-9FAA8012C8F52351/environmental%20Testing%20Survey.doc.)" from Nasa, these temperatures are only valid in a [Transatmospheric orbit (TAO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transatmospheric_orbit). Due to atmosferic drag these orbits are unstable and not much used. ...

Comment: In a [Low Earth Orbit (LEO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit), temperatures range from -65 ºC to +125 ºC and in a [Geostationary orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit) temperatures range from -196 ºC to +128 °C. Nevertheless, these are still quite high temperatures.

Comment: also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_panels_on_spacecraft

Comment: @MikeScott, this article is about the thermal insulation of spacecraft.
there is nothing about the functioning of solar panels.

Comment: @anna-v, I looked at similar articles before posting. there is nothing about the problem identified.
only the problem of the influence of cosmic radiation is mentioned, but this is completely different.

Comment: @VladimirOrlov  from the article  "The satellite was powered by silicon solar cells with ≈10% conversion efficiency."" further down "This led them to pioneer the development of multi-junction cells that increased efficiency from around 12% for their 1970s silicon cells to about 30% for their current gallium arsenide (GaAs) cells. These types of cells are now used almost universally on all solar-powered spacecraft"  .look at Future uses"

Comment: @annav v  however, that doesn't change the question.
Let's say now most of the cells in space are AsGa.
Then the question is: how did silicon panels work in space before?
In addition, AsGa cells are also dependent on temperature and its differences, although to a lesser extent. Much less information is available on AsGa. But I doubt that it will be able to work effectively at cosmic temperatures.

Comment: @VladimirOrlov " how did silicon panels work in space before?"  . Not very efficiently. The temperatures you quote have no  meaning unless the sun impinges on a surface  with particles  where temperature has a meaning,  Can you give a link for the numbers -260 and +200-300? measured on what?

Comment: @annav v ,  The_spider wrote about it in the post above. Nevertheless,  temperature and temperature difference is too large. The problem of overheating exists even in earthly conditions, although not so acute.